# bootstrap tooltip css is not the same as the official example

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using `bootstrap tooltip`, but the style is **not** the same as the official example.
I've imported `bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css`, and using like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

But the tooltip style shows like:

[image]

which I want is:
[image]

So could someone tell me what I missed ? Thanks
http://plnkr.co/edit/K21dTDcDqAUmasi3yrDd?p=preview

Comment: Can you create a SO code snippet of this behavior rather than providing a screenshot? Also, state precisely what the incorrect behavior is and what the desired behavior is.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for your advice, I've edited my question, and attach a plunker link, thanks for your help

Comment: Please post the code *in the question* itself. Right now one can only guess what the original problem was or what was done to fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your tooltip first. As per the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), the code is here:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Place the above code within `<script></script>` just before `</body>`

**Edit 1:**

Always include jQuery script before the Twitter bootstrap reference.

So the optimal code for your solution is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

 <!-- jQuery First -->
 <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Bootstrap Reference next -->
 <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </head>
<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on Right">Tooltip on Right</button>

<script>

  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); // Initialize Tooltip

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: hi, could you modify the plunker demo ? Nothing changed when I add this js code. thanks.  http://plnkr.co/edit/K21dTDcDqAUmasi3yrDd?p=preview

Comment: BTW two things were wrong, first the jQuery after Bootstrap, next there was no initialization for the tooltip earlier.

Comment: Without the original code readers aren't able to see what this answer fixes. While that's the OP's responsibility, you should probably make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

The `<script>` for jQuery must come **before** the `<script>` tag for Bootstrap. You have them in the wrong order. If you looked at the JavaScript console, you would have seen:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
(index):16 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
```

which is indicative of this mistake.